# How to reshape high-dimensional data frame from long to wide for subsequent dimension reduction + visualization?

Tags: python, pandas, dask, reshape

I have a data frame that resembles the following:

This looks like the following:

| index | attribute | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user_1 | a | 0.144228 |
| user_1 | b | 0.980685 |
| user_1 | c | 0.165716 |
| user_2 | a | 0.795340 |
| user_2 | b | 0.903498 |
| user_3 | d | 0.193492 |
| user_3 | e | 0.900509 |

Here's the reproducible code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'index':['user_1','user_1','user_1','user_2','user_2','user_3','user_3'],
                   'attribute':['a','b','c','a','b','d','e'],
              'score':[random.rand(),random.rand(),random.rand(),random.rand(),random.rand(),random.rand(),random.rand()]})


df.set_index('index',inplace=True)
```

I'd like to unstack/pivot this table so that the attribute values becomes column header, like so:

[image]

Now, this is fairly easy, except, I have **350K dimensions**, and as you can see from the above example, **not every user has scores for each dimension**.

I've tried using the standard pandas `pd.pivot_table()` and `.unstack()` functions, but my kernel invariably dies when I attempt to do so. I subsequently attempted to do so using dask, saving the output to a csv via

```
dask.dataframe.reshape.pivot_table(df, index='index', columns='attribute', values='score').to_csv('df.csv')
```

but that crashed too, yielding the following error:

`KilledWorker: ("('pivot_table_count-chunk-c31649485f27d5f8670393d66e2d14ac', 0, 3, 0)", <Worker 'tcp://127.0.0.1:56298', name: 0, memory: 0, processing: 5>)`

I'm currently at a loss. How can I reshape high-dimensional dataset for subsequent dimension reduction, clustering, and viz?

Answer (score 0):

```
df.pivot(index='index', columns='attribute').reset_index().droplevel(0, axis=1)


           attribute    a         b         c         d         e
0          user_1  0.144228  0.980685  0.165716       NaN       NaN
1          user_2  0.795340  0.903498       NaN       NaN       NaN
2          user_3       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.193492  0.900509
```

Comment: Yes, I understand how to use the stack/unstack/pivot functions, but this does not address the central problem of kernel death and memory constraints for a large, high-dimensional data set.

Comment: Yes, I've tried pivoting, as well as unstacking. My kernel dies regardless of which of these variants I use.

Comment: These are optimised methods and functions. A kernel dies because of memory issues or poor data structures. We cant tell unless if it were possible to reproduce your real life problem. It is not necessarily a pandas problem. Maybe try run in databricks notebooks because they use multiple nodes and scale up and down. My two bob take

Comment: Mhmm, I'm open to anything at this point. I don't necessarily have to work in pandas, it' just the environment I'm most comfortable in, and don't have experience working with high-dimensional data. Thanks for the data bricks recommendation, I'll give it a shot; let me know if you have any other ideas!